# Как исключить необходимость использования прав администратора при запуске процесса из приложения C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, solidworks

Мое приложение должно запускать процессы для последующего доступа к ним через API. Однако Windows 10 просит для методов запуска процессов права администратора. В противном случае программа работает с ошибкой. Как применять методы запуска процессов без необходимости использования прав администратора?

Первоначальный вариант кода (с сокращениями):

```
        //Функция копирования файлов в папку пользователя
    int int_Copy_files(All_box_parametres Box_parametres)
    {
     
        // Переменные для работы с объектами SW
        SldWorks^ swApp = nullptr;
        IPartDoc^ Part;
        bool boolstatus;
        int longstatus;
        int longwarnings;
        int swErrors;
        int swWarnings;
        
    
        //Флаг наличия предварительно запущенного SW
        bool bool_SW_process_flag;

    
        //Имя запущенного процесса SW
        TCHAR szExe[] = L"SldWorks.exe";

        //Если SW не запущен, то запускаем
        System::Object^ processSW;
        
        if (!IsProcessPresent((wchar_t*)&szExe))
        {
            processSW = System::Activator::CreateInstance(System::Type::GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid::Parse("{0D825E02-9000-4D82-B4AB-D6BDC2872797}")));
            swApp = (SldWorks^)processSW;
            swApp->Visible = true;
            bool_SW_process_flag = false;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Также я попробовал другой метод, но и он просит права администратора:

```
Process^ myProcess = gcnew Process();
        myProcess->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess->StartInfo->FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\SolidWorks Corp\\SolidWorks\\SLDWORKS.exe";
        myProcess->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess->Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось при использовании другой функции:

ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SolidWorks 2013\SolidWorks 2013 x64 Edition.lnk", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);

Эта функция также позволяет запустить конкретную версию приложения.